# Error while downloading census tiger data: 304 Not Modified

Tags: postgis, geocoding, census, tiger

I'm running `nation_script_load.sh` but I'm getting several errors and the data isn't been downloaded:

First one is:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
```

Second one:

```
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/gis/gisdata/temp//www2.census.gov': Is a directory
nation_script_load.sh: 17: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 18: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
```

Because of this I'm not getting any file downloaded.

Bellow the full log:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-115:/tmp$ sudo  sh nation_script_load.sh 
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2017-07-17 17:35:57--  https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2016/STATE/tl_2016_us_state.zip
Resolving www2.census.gov (www2.census.gov)... 104.68.125.234, 2600:1406:20:19e::208c, 2600:1406:20:1a0::208c
Connecting to www2.census.gov (www2.census.gov)|104.68.125.234|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2016/STATE/tl_2016_us_state.zip’ not modified on server. Omitting download.

rm: cannot remove '/tmp/gis/gisdata/temp//www2.census.gov': Is a directory
nation_script_load.sh: 17: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 18: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
Archive:  tl_2016_us_state.zip
 extracting: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_state.cpg  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_state.dbf  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_state.prj  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_state.shp  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_state.shp.ea.iso.xml  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_state.shp.iso.xml  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_state.shp.xml  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_state.shx  
nation_script_load.sh: 22: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 23: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 23: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 24: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 25: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 26: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2017-07-17 17:35:57--  https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2016/COUNTY/tl_2016_us_county.zip
Resolving www2.census.gov (www2.census.gov)... 104.68.125.234, 2600:1406:20:1a0::208c, 2600:1406:20:19e::208c
Connecting to www2.census.gov (www2.census.gov)|104.68.125.234|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2016/COUNTY/tl_2016_us_county.zip’ not modified on server. Omitting download.

rm: cannot remove '/tmp/gis/gisdata/temp//www2.census.gov': Is a directory
nation_script_load.sh: 31: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 32: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
Archive:  tl_2016_us_county.zip
 extracting: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_county.cpg  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_county.dbf  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_county.prj  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_county.shp  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_county.shp.ea.iso.xml  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_county.shp.iso.xml  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_county.shp.xml  
  inflating: /tmp/gis/gisdata/temp/tl_2016_us_county.shx  
nation_script_load.sh: 36: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 37: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 37: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 38: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 39: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 40: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 41: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 42: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 43: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
nation_script_load.sh: 44: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
```

EDIT:

I did:

```
which psql
```

The ouput was:

```
/usr/bin/psql
```

But I can't go to that location:

```
cd /usr/bin/psql

-bash: cd: /usr/bin/psql: Not a directory
```

I can only change to:

```
/usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the path to your postgresql bin set wrong.

This is the cause of your problems

```
nation_script_load.sh: 36: nation_script_load.sh: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql: not found
```

/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/shp2pgsql

You might have it set as part of your default env path, in which case you might be able to omit the variable path in the .sh script.

alternatively set path right

check with

```
which psql
```